# Solving four inequalities in three unknowns

Tags: inequalities

I would like to solve the following set of inequalities in Mathematica.

$$m \geq 1$$

$$n \geq 1$$

$$d > 5$$

$$d - \frac{m}{2}(d-2) - n(d-1) > 0 $$

I get *no solutions* by hand. I'd like to check this answer using Mathematica.

How do I do this in Mathemtica?

Comment: Why do you need *Mathematica* for this? Obviously, the second and third term are negative and smallest (in magnitude) for `m=1` and `n=1`. Even then the result is `-1/2 d + 2` which is `<0`.

Comment: `Reduce[{m >= 1, n >= 1, d > 5, d - m/2 (d - 2) - n (d - 1) > 0}]` returns `False` indicating that the conditions are inconsistent.

Comment: @ felix . I have it by hand, but I want to check my answer using all possible means.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce gives False instantaneously and FindInstance gives an empty list. So your surmise of no solution seems to be correct.

```
Reduce[{d - m/2 (d - 2) - n (d - 1) > 0, m >= 1, n >= 1, 
      d > 5}, {m, n, d}]

    (* False *)

FindInstance[{d - m/2 (d - 2) - n (d - 1) > 0, m >= 1, n >= 1,
   d > 5}, {m, n, d}]

(* {} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Felix 's response is best but if you had to do it with *Mathematica*:

```
Maximize[{m + n - d (m/2 + n), m >= 1 && n >= 1 && d > 5}, {m, n, d}]
```

> Maximize::wksol: Warning: there is no maximum in the region in which
>   the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; a
>   result on the boundary will be returned.

```
{-(11/2), {m -> 1, n -> 1, d -> 5}}
```